# Theorem List Template for Course Modules

Tags: table-of-contents

I'd like to create a template in latex that will list the theorems and definitions that I have entered.

For example, in my Analysis 1 module, I have learnt Theorem 2.21 $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}(a_n + b_n) = \alpha + \beta $

Ideally I'd like to enter it into a document titled **Analysis 1**, and under **Chapter 2 - Sequences**, I'd have an entry stating **Theorem 2.21** $ \lim_{x \to +\infty}(a_n + b_n) = \alpha + \beta $

I'm a complete beginner, could someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,

Ash

Comment: What do you mean by "a module" and "section them appropriately"? Please clarify.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're absolutely right! Hopefully I've clarified a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this can give you a starting point:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% We define two structures: one for theorems and another one for definitions
% since we used \newtheorem* (with a star) for definitions, the
% definitions won't be numbered
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sequences}

\begin{defi}
A sequence of real numbers (or simply a sequence) is a function from a subset of the natural numbers to the real numbers.
\end{defi}

\begin{theo}
Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two sequences such that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}a_n=\alpha$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}b_n=\beta$, then
\[
\lim_{x \to +\infty}(a_n + b_n) = \alpha + \beta.
\]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

You should consider reading a basic introduction to LaTeX.